# Call method from interface or abstract class within static void

Tags: c#, class, methods, interface, static

I'm usually a javascript developer, but for my company I just started learning c# in order to use the CimatronE 13 API to develop custom command line PDM tools for this 3D modelling software.

As I'm making progress understanding the programming language, there's this frustrating situation where I want to use an API endpoint method but I can't manage to get it working.

The Cimatron documentation says the following:

> **IPdm::GetRelatedDocuments**
>
> **Syntax**: RelatedDocuments = GetRelatedDocuments ( DocumentPath );
>
> This method allows you to get related files from compound types of files, for example Assembly or Drawing.
>
> **Input**: (String) DocumentPath,
>   Path to file. For example \Documents\Location\Folder\Document. The file must be Assembly or Drawing.
>
> **Return**: (Variant) RelatedDocuments,
>    Variant type array each element of which contain two dimensioned string type array of files related to selected one.

This looks pretty straight forward to me, so I tried calling it in multiple ways from within the `static void Main()` method, but I keep getting errors:

```
var RelatedDocuments = interop.CimBaseAPI.IPdm.GetRelatedDocuments("path");
```

> CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'IPdm.GetRelatedDocuments(string)'

```
interop.CimBaseAPI.IPdm pdm = new interop.CimBaseAPI.IPdm();
var RelatedDocuments = pdm.GetRelatedDocuments("path");
```

> CS0144: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IPdm'

Any ideas? It's probably simple but I'm still a noob with c# :p

**EDIT:**

Cimatron documentation about the interface `interop.CimBaseAPI.IPdm`:

> **Properties:**
>
> Get
>    Query (String, DocumentEnumType, DocumentEnumUnit )
>    Variant
>
> **Methods:**
>
> A lot, including `Variant GetRelatedDocuments ( String )`

Comment: Does the vendor not provide examples of how to use their product?  If the `IPdm` class is abstract or an interface then you indeed can't directly create an instance of it.  But presumably they would have a class which implements the `IPdm` class/interface.

Comment: check the documentation if there are any types that implement `IPdm`

Comment: Is `interop.CimBaseAPI.IPdm` as class or an interface?

Comment: Perhaps you need to call `GetPdm( )` first and call `GetRelatedDocuments(path)` on the returned instance.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Unfortunately, their documentation is really poor and they don't supply examples (they would be very helpful indeed). @vc74: `interop.CimBaseAPI.IPdm` is an interface. @linuxrocks: what do you mean by `GetPdm()`.

Comment: According to the documentation I found there is a method `GetPdm()` that returns an `IPdm` instance.

Comment: Can you try `var access = new AppAccess(); IApplication application = access.GetApplication(); IPdm Pdm = application.GetPdm(); var RelatedDocuments = Pdm.GetRelatedDocuments("path");`

Comment: Thanks! I found it as well. I'm trying to understand how casting works as I'm now figuring out that more steps are needed before being able to use IPdm. I hope to find a working solution. Thanks guys! @vc74: I will try as well, let you know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As how I see it now... `interop.CimatronE.IPdm` is an interface and in order to use it's methods, we first need access to the Cimatron application. Using the application object, we can use it's methods to get the desired interfaces such as `IPdm` and use their methods.

The following code gives no errors from the compiler but does when executing. This seems to be related to version 13 of CimatronE, since the application object works just fine using version 12. A lot has changed between these versions which I think is the reason the API is not functioning properly, outdated.

```
interop.CimAppAccess.AppAccess AppAcc = new interop.CimAppAccess.AppAccess();
interop.CimatronE.IApplication CimApp = /*(interop.CimatronE.IApplication)*/AppAcc.GetApplication();

interop.CimatronE.IPdm pdm = CimApp.GetPdm();

var RelatedDocuments = pdm.GetRelatedDocuments("path");
Console.WriteLine(RelatedDocuments);
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong! (since I just started and still learning c#)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue with Cimatron 14.
I needed to make some changes in Visual Studio for things run properly with Cimatron.

- Run Visual Studio in administrator mode
- Set your Debug & Release Solution Platform to 'x64'
- It was also recommended to point the build path for release & debug to the same folder as the Cimatron references. In my case 'C:\Program Files\3D Systems\Cimatron\14.0\Program'. However my code appears to run fine without this.

I created the Cimatron Application with this code (VB.Net):

```
    Dim gAppAccess As New CIMAPPACCESSLib.AppAccess 'Define an AppAccess object to get running active application
    Dim gApp As CIMAPPACCESSLib.Application 'Define an Application object
    gApp = gAppAccess.GetApplication 'Getting running active application
    If gApp Is Nothing Then
        gApp = New CIMAPPACCESSLib.Application 'Creating a new instance of a Cimatron application
    End If
```

References: Interop.CIMAPPACCESSLib.dll & interop.CimServicesAPI.dll

It is my understanding that Cimatron 15 may also requires some manifest changes.

There is some help information in the Cimatron program under **Cimatrom Modules > Cimaton SDK** that may be mildly helpful.